Проверить, какие товары имеются (запятая) и к каким категориям относятся

Необходимо проверить, какие товары имеются и к каким категориям они относятся.

Нужна ли здесь запятая перед "и"? И почему?

Не нужна. Придаточные имеют общее главное: "Необходимо проверить".

Однородными называются предложения, которые имеют некую общую
структуру: общее главное предложение, общее придаточное предложение,
общее вводное слово или общий второстепенный член. Эти предложения
соединены или могут быть соединены сочинительными союзами,
произносятся с интонацией перечисления.

